# ERR Connection Refused over HTTPS IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2016

I purchased a certificate so that I could have SSL on my home web server.

I am using dynamic DNS and able to connect to the various websites I have configured over HTTP.

I have the bindings set to use the certificate over HTTPS on port 443.  If I attempt to navigate to the site via `https://example.org` - I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I am running Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I recently replaced my home router with a newer mesh router.  I thought I had opened all of the port forwarding I am using (RDP, HTTP, HTTPS and FTP) - but 443 was not set-up.

It threw me off because I had SSL working for years - but I had this certificate expire so I didn't realize the problem was blocked port immediately when I upgraded the router.